# A number of men enter a disreputable establishment

Tags: combinatorics

A number of men enter a disreputable establishment and each one leaves a coat and
an umbrella at the door. When a message is received saying that the establishment is about
to be raided by the police, the men leave hurriedly, and no man gets both the right coat and
the umbrella. If there are n men, show that the number of ways in which this can happen is
$$n!\left( n!-\frac{(n-1)!}{1!} + \frac{(n-2)!}{2!}-...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \right)  $$

Comment: Google “derangement.”

Comment: I think this is kind of different.

Comment: From the form of the formula, it appears an inclusion/exclusion argument is used (alternating signs).

Comment: Maybe thinking it in this way will help you reach the solution early: Total number of arrangements-Number of arrangements that violate the given condition

Answer (score 2):

Let the number of ways in which this can happen for $n$ people be $D_n.$ For each $1\le i \le n,$ let $C_i$ be the set of arrangements in which person $i$ gets both of his items back.

Then by inclusion-exclusion, $D_n = (n!)^2 - \sum |C_i| + \sum |C_i\cap C_j| + \ldots$

But $|C_i| = [(n-1)!]^2,$ $|C_i\cap C_j| = [(n-2)!]^2,$ etc. Clearly the number of terms in each sum involving $k$ people is $\binom{n}{k},$ so the formula follows easily.